# Flex box last item taking full width of the container. How can i resolve this?

Tags: html, list, css, flexbox

The last row item takes full width however I want the last row item to have the same width as all the other items. 
I have attached a screenshot illustrating my problem.

Is it feasible with flexbox or i have to use simple css for my requirement? Or I Should use Display Table and table-cell property?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px
}

.listingResult {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listingResult>li {
  width: 33.33%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 33.33%;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1 .33%;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 1 33.33%;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1 33.33%;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1 33.33%;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listingResult>li .listingResultPic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.listingResult>li .listingResultInfo {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="listingResult">
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,000</h4>
        <p class="address info">Co Rd AFChampion, MI 49814</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1103145">1103145</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">1</li>
          <li class="area">1103 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,500</h4>
        <p class="address info">GenevaIronwood, MI 49938</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1100143">1100143</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">2</li>
          <li class="area">1717 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,500</h4>
        <p class="address info">SaginawNorway, MI 49870</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1104097">1104097</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">1</li>
          <li class="area">828 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,900</h4>
        <p class="address info">NorthWakefield, MI 49968</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1101426">1101426</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">2</li>
          <li class="area">935 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Then just use grid system, flexbox is intended for 1D control whereas `grid` is for 2D control. `display: grid;  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px, 1fr));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set flex-grow to 0. Change `flex: 1 33.33%` to `flex: 0 1 33.33%` on the list element.

Here is your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/ecgx58ep/2/

See this link for more information on flex-grow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Answer (score 3):

You can change `flex: 1 33.33%` to `flex: 0 1 33.33%`. Now `flex-grow` will be *disabled* and the last row will behave.

As you are already setting `flex-basis` of 33.33% in `flex: 0 1 33.33%`, you can remove the `width: 33.33%`.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px
}

.listingResult {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listingResult>li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 0 1 .33%;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listingResult>li .listingResultPic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.listingResult>li .listingResultInfo {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="listingResult">
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,000</h4>
        <p class="address info">Co Rd AFChampion, MI 49814</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1103145">1103145</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">1</li>
          <li class="area">1103 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,500</h4>
        <p class="address info">GenevaIronwood, MI 49938</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1100143">1100143</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">2</li>
          <li class="area">1717 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,500</h4>
        <p class="address info">SaginawNorway, MI 49870</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1104097">1104097</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">1</li>
          <li class="area">828 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listingResultPic"><img src="http://rets.906mls.com/mls_photos/1102784_1.JPG" alt="No Image" width=""></div>
      <div class="listingResultInfo">
        <h4 class="price">$12,900</h4>
        <p class="address info">NorthWakefield, MI 49968</p>
        <p class="listingNumber info">Listing Number: <a href="http://182.73.133.220/elder/listing-details/1101426">1101426</a></p>
        <ul class="basicInfo">
          <li class="bed">3</li>
          <li class="bath">2</li>
          <li class="area">935 sqft</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*somehow this could do the trick ?? *

```css
                html, body{ background-color:yellow;
                height:100%;width:100%;
                }

                *, body,html, a {
                  box-sizing: border-box;
                  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                  margin:0;padding:0;
                }

                body{overflow-x:auto;
                }

                .container {  
                    display:flex;
                    flex-flow: row wrap;  
                    max-width:1200px;  
                    width:98%;
                    height:auto;
                    min-height:40vh;
                    border:1px solid red; 
                    background-color:white; 
                    margin:0 auto;
                }

                .container > div{
                  min-width: 30%; 
                 flex:1 30%;
                  align-self:stretch; /* ? */

                    border:1px solid blue; 
                    background-color:lime;
                    margin:1rem;
                }

                p{margin:1rem;}
```

```html
                <body>
                <div class="container"> 
                <div>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
                Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
                Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                 Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
                 imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. <br/>
                </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <p>
                 Men do not roar. Women roar. Then they hurl heavy objects... and claw at you.
                 ( Lt. Worf)
                 </p>
                 <p>
                 Klingons do not procrastinate. It is a tactical delay.
                 </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <p>
                 Integer tincidunt. 
                 Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, 
                 porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, 
                 feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                 Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                 <p>
                </p>
                 Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem 
                 neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. 
                 Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. 
                 Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla 
                 mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. 
                </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <p>
                 Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. 
                 Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla 
                 mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. 
                </p>
                </div>
                </div><!-- end  div #container -->
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).